# Make div tags adjacent in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a design for my website mobile layout.

I have a section that has something similar to :

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
```

Obviously, these 4 `div` tags appear adjacent to each other.

I need this section to appear in mobile in pairs. In which each 2 `div` tags appear adjacent to each other.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add more classes to the divs -- say

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
```

This would make each 6 units wide (out of 12) on "medium" displays, rather than the 3 units each on "large" displays.

Whether you use `md` or `sm` etc depends on what screen size you want the change to occur.

The "[Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/)" are helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen P

Answer (score 1):

Each pair needs to be wrapped inside a div using a class you can control the position of the inner div.

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> Some html </div>
</div>
```